# Display the latest comment entered

Tags: php, mysql

I have a posts table and a comments table where for a single post there will be number of comments added to it.There is a php table where I display the data.
In this table i want to display the the latest comment for a post when ever it is added.

Post table,where the posts are added:

```
       Posts 
+-------+---------+
|  id   | Post    |
+-------+---------+
|   1   |   ABC   |
|   2   |   DEF   |
|   3   |   GHI   |
+-------+---------+
```

Comment table where number of comments will be added to a particular post:

```
   Comments
+----------+---------+
|  Post_id | Comment |
+----------+---------+
|   1      |   A     |
|   1      |   D     |
|   3      |   F     |
|   3      |   V     |
|   3      |   B     |
+----------+---------+
```

Here post_id is taken from the id of the post table.

I want the post with a latest comment to be displayed in this table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Post</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach($results as $key=>$row) { ?>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $row['Comment'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

For example:

```
+----------+---------+
|  Post    | Comment |
+----------+---------+
|   ABC    |   D     |
|   GHI    |   B     |
+----------+---------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your related table structures (`create table code`)

Comment: Given that rows in an RDBMS represent unordered sets, define "latest".

Comment: Add one extra column `id` to the table `Comments` with auto increment.  Later, you can print the result by sorting with id "ORDER BY id DESC"

Comment: after the primary key column is added what would be the query statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you!

```
SELECT comment FROM comments WHERE comment_id = (SELECT comment_id 
FROM comments WHERE post_id = 1 ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 1);`
```

***Table Structure***

[image: Table Structure]

***Table Data***

[image: Table Data]

***Query Result***

[image: Query Result]

Comment: Try this - `SELECT post from posts where post_id = 1 UNION SELECT comment FROM comments WHERE comment_id = (SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE post_id =1 ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 1)`

Comment: Or, you can use 2 separate queries all together. `SELECT post from posts where post_id = 1` to get the post with the post_id of 1 and `SELECT comment FROM comments WHERE comment_id = (SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE post_id =1 ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 1)` to get the last comment on the post with a post_id of 1.

Comment: Kindly accept and up-vote my answer if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

In the current state they are no easy and optimally way to do it. I would suggest you to add an id field in your current `Comments` table.

Comment: I think OP's table representation is just too much schematical, we can't really tell if it lacks a primary key or not

Comment: In its current state, should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Sakuto answer

Give ID for the comments table also, and AUTO_INCREMENT it. When you select comments of particular post get their corresponding comments and display them using associated comment IDs. May be you need to display them higher number(ID) to lower number(ID). Make ID as Primary key.

Answer (score 0):

complete solution. You may add a current_date column in Comments table with a

```
TIMESTAMP datatype
```

and set

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default
```

It will add current date and time, whenever there is a new comment. Then, add in your sql query.

```
order by current_date desc
```

It will return the latest comment first.